# systemVerilog - How can I convert int unsigned to array logic?

Tags: casting, system-verilog

I have the following :

```
logic [15:0] tb_real_din, tb_image_din;
int unsigned counter;

   //write proc
   initial begin
      tb_last_dvalid = 1'b0;
      tb_we = 1'b0;
      #80ns;
      for (int i = 0 ; i <= 32; i++)
    begin
       counter = counter+1;
       tb_real = counter;
       tb_image = counter;
       if (i == 32)        
         tb_last_dvalid = 1'b1;
       #8ns;
       tb_we = 1'b1;
       #8ns;
       tb_we = 1'b0;
       tb_last_dvalid = 1'b0;      
    end     
   end // initial begin
```

I got the following error:
 Illegal reference to net "tb_real".
How can I convert int unsigned to array logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is nothing to do with converting between types. Your problem is probably because you have not declared `tb_real`. Anything undeclared in System-verilog defaults to being a 1-bit `wire`; a `wire` is a kind of *net* and it is illegal to assign to nets from `initial`, `always` or `final` blocks. Hence, your error message.

I say "probably" because you have not give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).